# Multi-threading use of SQLAlchemy Sessions

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy, python-multithreading

I've been reading about the multi-threading use of the Sqlalchemy session, but still wonder if it is the best way to use one global session for multiple threads and allow only one thread to use it at once or to limit the number of sessions created and make a new session per thread and have like a limit on the number of sessions running together. In my project, I need to make several requests simultaneously, and while I wait for the response to those requests, the session is still active. Once the response is received, I add it to the PostgreSQL DB and close the session. Up to 6-7 requests per second are fine and 85 concurrent sessions seem to be enough, but when I increase it to 8-9 requests per second, due to larger response time, many sessions get stuck and don't close in time.

```
    def plan_request(self, url, time_num):
        logger.info(f'Sleeping for {time_num} seconds')
        session_manager = GetNewLocalSession()
        time.sleep(time_num)
        # after delay new session is created using session manager I made
        session_local = session_manager.get_new_local_session()
        self.tool.test(session_local, item)
        self.session_manager.remove_local_session(session_local)
        session_local.close()
        db.Session.remove()
```

```
class GetNewLocalSession():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sessions = []
    
    def get_new_local_session(self):
        print(f"Sessions used: {len(self.sessions)}")
        if len(self.sessions) <= 85:
            # creates new scoped_session object
            session_local = Session()
            self.sessions.append(session_local)
            return session_local
        else:
            success = False
            while not success:
                if len(self.sessions) <= 85:
                    session_local = Session()
                    self.sessions.append(session_local)
                    success = True
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.1)
            return session_local

    def remove_local_session(self, session_local):
        if session_local in self.sessions:
            self.sessions.remove(session_local)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You usually use a scoped session for this.  But it sounds like the real problem is a combination of insufficient connections in the connection pool and requests (queries?) that take too long to complete.

Comment: I do use scoped session, the real question is if it is better to open a new session for each thread and then close when done or somehow use one session, but limited only to one thread using it at the time. The problem now is that when adding more requests, the sessions stay open longer and don't close, therefore not allowing other sessions to open. Therefore stopping the whole script.

Comment: If it doesn't matter if a single outbound request "fails" then one session per thread might work - or even better open the session to do db work, close and remove, send the request, open a new session to process the response.  If failure does matter - that is the db might be left in an inconsistent state - then a single session in the main thread and other threads that make outbound requests but do no database work.

Comment: Even better, if it's within your control, on receiving an inbound request, dispatch all the work to some kind of background worker and respond with a reference. Let the requesting app poll your app until the background worker has completed all the requests.